# Nested Pivot control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

Is it Possible to have a nested Pivot control in WP7. 
Like I was a pivot page 1,2,3
and inside 1, I want to have page a,b,c. 
Is it possible to control it only within MainPage.xaml?

I want the old pivot 1,2,3 to disappear on click on 1 and instead have a,b,c as the main pivot headers. Is it possible?

Comment: Even if this is possible I'd strongly suggest this isn't going to be a loved Metro experience - it's probably better to use a different UI design - e.g. separate pages - rather than to confuse the users with this disappearing parent pivot design.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd HIDE the main pivot, but I personally don't see any issue with nesting pivots +to a point+. Wouldn't want to do it just because you can, and you definitely have to deal with stopping the out pivot from shifting when you shift the inner pivot, but that's fairly easy to do by trapping the ManipulationStarted as mentioned in an answer. I've played with this construct a little and the end result is perfectly intuitive and in keeping with the Metro feel IMO.

Comment: Ah, found the article about doing this here

http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/12/09/WP7-Tip-disabling-the-Pivot-Control-swipe-gesture.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is generally possible. However, I would highly recommend not to do it, as it will confuse the user and will add you more work to do (as per handling navigation between pivots instead of pages). So let's say I have a sample `Pivot` control:

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="HostPivot" Title="MY APPLICATION">
<controls:PivotItem x:Name="MainPivot" Header="first">
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="sPivot" Title="Secondary Pivot">
        <controls:PivotItem x:Name="sPivotItem" Header="inside1"></controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="inside2"></controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="inside3"></controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</controls:PivotItem>

<controls:PivotItem x:Name="SecondaryPivot" Header="second"> 
</controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Whenever I will try to navigate inside the second `Pivot` control (with the active host), `HostPivot` will intercept the manipulation and move to the next pivot item inside it instead of `sPivot`.

What to do in this case? Detect the manipulation:

`sPivot.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(sPivot_ManipulationStarted);`

So you will eventually have this piece to replace the host pivot with the secondary one:

```
void sPivot_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainPivot.Content != null)
    {
        MainPivot.Content = null;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(HostPivot);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(sPivot);
    }
}
```

You'd have to remove the secondary `Pivot` control from the set of child controls of the first `PivotItem` in the host `Pivot` control and add it to the main grid (`LayoutRoot`).

This will eventually raise the question - do you really want to implement the navigation this way (between pivots) when it's clearly easier and more efficient to navigate between separate `PhoneApplicationPage` entitites.

Comment: I'm not able to still hide the main pivot control. Where should I be using the 
sPivot.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(sPivot_ManipulationStarted);

I tried it inside the GestureListener_Tap. Did not workout:(

Comment: Put it in the initialization sector - in the page constructor.